Unable to integrate Firebase into Flutter project
I tried on integrating Firebase into the project for the first time but I am unable to run it in my Flutter App.
I have tried installing Firebase into my system. I downloaded Firebase CLI from the website and also added following dependencies:
firebase_core: ^3.2.0
firebase_auth: ^5.1.2
cloud_firestore: ^5.1.0
firebase_storage: ^12.1.1
dash_chat_2: ^0.0.21
firebase_analytics: ^11.2.0

I have already added this to path address in environment variable settings, but when I run flutterfire configure as shown in youtube videos, I get following error:

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.

And when I run on Command Prompt, this shows:

D:\FLUTTER PROJECTS\riverpod_course>flutterfire configure
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.


On which operating system are you working? The FlutterFire CLI requires the Firebase CLI to be installed beforehand. It seems you might be missing the Firebase CLI, which is why the firebase --version command fails

Complete the installation using the npm install -g firebase-tools command and then you can install the CLI using the dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli command.
Note : Make sure you have nodejs/npm installed on your computer before using the npm install -g firebase-tools command.

I encountered the same issue. Here's an alternative method for adding Firebase to your project using Fast Node Manager instead of the Firebase CLI binary:
Installing Fast Node Manager
First, install Fast Node Manager using PowerShell:
# installs fnm (Fast Node Manager)
winget install Schniz.fnm

# create required environment
fnm env --use-on-cd | Out-String | Invoke-Expression

# download and install Node.js
fnm use --install-if-missing 20

# verifies the right Node.js version is in the environment
node -v # should print `v20.15.1`

# verifies the right NPM version is in the environment
npm -v # should print `10.7.0`

Adding Firebase
Next, add Firebase to your project:
# install firebase tools
npm install -g firebase-tools

# login to firebase account you want to connect to your project
firebase login

# activate flutterfure cli
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

# Navigate to your project directory and run the following command to config your project
flutterfire configure

Finally, ensure Firebase is initialized in your app by calling: await Firebase.initializeApp(); on your app.
